# Cython syntax for dataframe of dates and dictionaries as inputs to the function

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I am a python user with moderate experience in writing codes and recently I noticed that I can use cython for sequential models like backtesting codes to make it faster. The problem is that imagine I have a function called backtesting with arguments given below:

```
def backtest(daterange,price_dict,tickers_dict,):
return result
```

where daterange is a dataframe of dates.

price_dict is a dictionary of daily prices based on company ticker and date given (so it is a dictionary with 2 levels of keys --> price_dict[ticker][date] -> price

tickers_dict is a dictionary of picked tickers based on dates so it is like tickers_dict[date] --> gives a list of tickers

result is a dataframe with daily equity values of the portfolio calculated inside the function.

How can I define all of these in cython using cdef or cpdef? what is the syntax for it? It has driven me crazy t o find the right syntax!
thanks

Comment: 'dataframe' - as in `pandas`, or is that an informal way of describing a `numpy` array?  `shape` and `dtype` may be useful information.

Comment: I haven't looked at `cython` docs in awhile.  Do they mention `pandas` at all?

Comment: Have you done any `cython` before?  Start small with clear examples.

Comment: no i mean dataframe as in pandas. For example sth like this: pd.DataFrame(dates,column=['Dates'])

Comment: Yes I have done it in a limited capacity. just looked at this link about pandas in cython. My problem is I am not sure how to bring big dataframes or dictionaries as inputs to my cython function. this is the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html